# Is this valid in python: Instances being stored inside parent instance in a list of instances .?

Tags: python, list, object, instance

I was trying to create instances of a class from another class's instance.
So I wrote something simple to see how it works.
Is this method valid and useful which seems it works fine in this example..? Or  will it create problems or can it make things harder on further steps ?

```
import random

class family(object):

        def __init__(self,surname,numofmem,location):
            self.surname=surname
            self.numofmem=numofmem
            self.location=location
            self.relatives=[]
            self.rel2=None
            self.CreateMembers()

        def CreateMembers(self):
            for mem in range(0,self.numofmem):
                self.relatives.append(CreateAMember())

        def listMembers(self):
            for mem in self.relatives:
                print (mem.name+" "+self.surname+" lives in "+self.location)

class CreateAMember(object):

        listnames=["Aaron","Abbey","Abbie","Abby","Abdul","Abe","Abel","Abigail","Abraham"]

        def __init__(self):
            self.rnd=random.randint(0,len(self.listnames)-1)
            self.name=self.listnames[self.rnd]

myFamily=family("Reactor",5,"Canada")
myFamily.listMembers()
```

Comment: As this is working code, I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network, http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

On first sight I don't see anything wrong with your code. Python solves nearly everything with references, so storing objects in other objects does not necessarily pose problems with your memory, if that is what you're asking. E.g. the following code is also perfectly legal:

```
class bla():
    def __init__(self):
        self.reference_to_self = self
```

What kind of problems do you anticipate exactly?

Comment: I used this method in a longer code. This referencing has same concept :  print (mem.name+" "+self.surname+" lives in "+self.location).... But on that script i kept getting an Error message : That Error if i try to adapt to this code. it can be : (mem.name [ None object has no attribute .name.]) I did not still solve that in that longer code. maybe something inline so i do not see it .. I wrote this to see  .. It works fine i guess..